# First attempt at a distance object

Tags: php

In our code we deal with distances a lot, a distance being a number and unit

eg 15km, or 1.234mi

The current approach is to use 2 functions, `convert_distance()`, and `format_distance()`

Those 2 functions don't need review, but I will include their method signature here for reference.

```
function convert_distance(float $distance, string $output_unit, string $input_unit = 'km'): float

function format_distance(float $distance, int $dp, ?string $decimal_separator = null, ?string $thousands_separator = null): string;
```

this results in several instances where we call `format_distance(convert_distance(...), ...)`

We tried to come up with a Dist object that could handle conversions and formatting, although when it comes to comparisson and subtraction/multiplication etc, it seems more difficult then just using primatives.

I guess I am interested in 2 things

1. Is this a good approach or are we just making it harder for ourselves
2. Feedback on the code below

Example of how you would use this class

```
$d = new Dist(10, 'mi');
echo $d->format('km', 2);
```

Thanks in advance

```
<?php

namespace Lib;

use InvalidArgumentException;

class Dist {
    public const UNIT_KM = 'km';
    public const UNIT_MI = 'mi';

    public const CONVERSION_FACTOR_MI_TO_KM = 1.60934;
    public const CONVERSION_FACTOR_KM_TO_MI = 0.621371;

    private float $distance_km = 0.0;


    public function __construct(float $distance, string $unit = self::UNIT_KM) {
        $this->validate_unit($unit);

        $this->distance_km = $this->convert_to_km($distance, $unit);
    }


    private function validate_unit(string $unit): void {
        if (!in_array($unit, [self::UNIT_KM, self::UNIT_MI], true)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid Unit");
        }
    }


    private function convert_to_km(float $distance, string $unit): float {
        switch ($unit) {
            case self::UNIT_KM:
                // km to km, no conversion required
                $converted_distance = $distance;
                break;

            case self::UNIT_MI:
                $converted_distance = ($distance * self::CONVERSION_FACTOR_MI_TO_KM);
                break;

            default:
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid Unit");
        }

        return $converted_distance;
    }


    private function convert_to(string $unit): float {
        switch ($unit) {
            case self::UNIT_KM:
                // km to km, no conversion required
                $converted_distance = $this->distance_km;
                break;

            case self::UNIT_MI:
                $converted_distance = ($this->distance_km * self::CONVERSION_FACTOR_KM_TO_MI);
                break;

            default:
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid Unit");
        }

        return $converted_distance;
    }

    public function to_float(string $unit, int $dp = 3): float {
        $this->validate_unit($unit);

        $distance = $this->convert_to($unit);

        return round($distance, $dp);
    }


    public function format(string $unit, int $dp = 2, string $decimal_separator = '.', $thousands_separator = ','): string {
        $this->validate_unit($unit);
        
        return number_format($this->to_float($unit, $dp), $dp, $decimal_separator, $thousands_separator);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is quite a good class.

My biggest complaint is that it always converts incoming distances to kilometers. This conversion might be counterproductive when input and output are in miles. It also requires you to have two conversion methods, which looks very strange.

Some of your public method names seem very concerned with the inner workings of the class. A person using your class doesn't care. So, as an example, a method like `convert_to()` could be called `get_in_unit()`. The class should take care of any conversion, if needed.

I was also surprised to learn that your class doesn't contain [the official SI definition of a mile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile).

The `to_float()` method makes little sense, the distance is already a float. Ah, it's a rounding method. However, it is not needed for `number_format()` because that already does the rounding for you. So I removed the `to_float()` method.

Finally, you made the `$distance` property private, and it can only be set when the class is created. This can be a choice, but why restrict it like that? I added a setter for the distance.

I'm left with this code:

```
class Distance {

    public const UNIT_KILOMETERS = 'kilometers';
    public const UNIT_MILES = 'miles';

    private const KILOMETERS_IN_1MILE = 1.609344; 

    private float $distance = 0.0;
    private string $unit = self::UNIT_KILOMETERS;

    public function __construct(float $distance, 
                                string $unit = self::UNIT_KILOMETERS) 
    {
        $this->set_distance($distance, $unit);
    }

    public function set_distance($distance, string $unit = ''): object
    {
        if (empty($unit)) {
            $unit = $this->unit;
        }
        if (!in_array($unit, [self::UNIT_KILOMETERS, self::UNIT_MILES])) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Unit [$unit]");
        }
        $this->distance = $distance; 
        $this->unit = $unit;
        return $this;
    }

    public function get_distance(string $unit = ''): float 
    {
        if (empty($unit)) {
            $unit = $this->unit;
        }
        if ($unit == $this->unit) {
            return $this->distance; 
        }
        switch ($unit) {
            case self::UNIT_KILOMETERS:
                return $this->distance * self::KILOMETERS_IN_1MILE;
            case self::UNIT_MILES:
                return $this->distance / self::KILOMETERS_IN_1MILE;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid Unit [$unit]");
        }
        return 0.0;
    }

    public function distance_format(string $unit = '', 
                                    int $decimal_point = 2, 
                                    string $decimal_separator = '.',
                                    $thousands_separator = ','): string 
    {
        return number_format($this->get_distance($unit), 
                             $decimal_point, 
                             $decimal_separator, 
                             $thousands_separator) .
               " " . 
               $unit;
    }

}
```

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/CJSEg

Notice how I removed almost all of your abbreviations. They are not needed and can only cause confusion. It took me a while to realize that `$dp` stands for "decimal point". Never leave your readers guessing what your names stand for.

Choosing names is one of the most important things to get right when creating classes. Hence I used `distance_format()` instead of just `format()`, to make clear what the method does, and to distinguish it from other "format" methods.

I added the ability to leave out the `$unit` argument from the methods. If this happens the internal value will be used.

You also talked about comparisons and simply math operations. I think this class can be useful there, especially when the "unit" of the things you compare is different. For instance, a compare method, that can compare two different "units" could look like this:

```
    public function distance_compare(float distance, string $unit = ''): int
    {
        $that = new Distance(distance, $unit);
        return $this->get_distance($unit) <=> $that->get_distance($unit);
    }
```

See: [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: thanks for you feedback, quite a bit to digest. +1 for the info on SI units. The intention with to_float vs format, was that some places in our api need a float that doesn't have a thousands seperator, and I didn't want to have to specify '' as a thousands separator, so just a shortcut for that really

Comment: Good answers otherwise, but why add a setter and break the immutability of the class? The answer could elaborate on the pros and cons of this.

Comment: @TomG I don't think that being immutable is important for this class. Perhaps you can, at least, come up with one good reason?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware generally, I think a good reason for immutability is that there is no strong argument against it.

Comment: @TomG Not everything has to be immutable, but it you prefer it, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the units to an enum. Or you can actually turn in into its own class and close the distance class for modification if you need more units in future.

```
final class Unit
{
  private static self $kilometers = null;
  private static self $miles = null;

  public function __construct(
    public readonly float $meters,
    public readonly string $abbreviation,
  ) {
  }

  public static function kilometers(): self
  {
     return self::$kilometers ??= new self(1000.0, 'km');
  }

  public static function miles(): self
  {
     return self::$miles ??= new self(1609.344, 'mi');
  }
}
```

I would also not abbreviate the class and argument names. And also the classes should be immutable.
I will also translate everything to meters as that is the SI unit. In fact, the class is meters specific and so I will name it Meters. And I can implement it against interface.
Also notice how turning the unit into its own class removed the need for validation in basically all methods.

```
interface DistanceInterface
{
  public function in(Unit $unit): float;
  public function format(Unit $unit): string
}
```

```
final class Meters implements DistanceInterface
{
  public function __construct(
    public readonly float $meters,
  ) {
  }

  public static function from(float $value, Unit $unit): self
  {
    return new self($value * $unit->meters);
  }

  public function in(Unit $unit): float
  {
     return $this->meters / $unit->meters;
  }

  public function format(Unit $unit): string
  { 
    return "{$this->in($unit)} {$unit->abbreviation}";
  }
}
```

I have removed the rounding and number formatting arguments for simplicity but you can add them back as needed.

```
$d = Meters::from(50, Unit::kilometers());
echo $d->format(Unit::miles());
```

However you should notice that it is still two statements, just as it was with `convert_distance()` and `format_distance()` functions. Thats because it simply are two responsibilities. See how this is reflected by providing a conversion method `from()` instead of passing unit to constructor.

You can use `==` to compare Meters instances and it will work as expected. I think it should work for `<`, `>`, etc. as well but I'm not sure now, I would usualy rather provide named methods anyway.

There is another way to think of the distance really as pair.

```
final class Distance
{
  public function __construct(
    public readonly float $value,
    public readonly Unit $unit,
  ) {
  }

  public function to(Unit $unit): self
  {
    return new self($this->value * $this->unit->meters / $unit->meters, $unit);
  }

  public function format(): string
  {
    return "{$this->value} {$this->unit->abbreviation}";
  }
}
```

```
$d = new Distance(50, Unit::kilometers())
echo $d->to(Unit::miles())->format();
```

Sligthly similar, depends what you find better to work with. However in this case default compariosion of instances is not possible unless the two instances have the same unit. Named methods for comparision must be provided. But as I said before, I would provide such methods anyway so it's not a big deal. Advantage of this approach is you dont convert the value to different unit until needed. Disadvantage is that you are creating yet another object on each conversion. And When adding two distances together you must invent some logic on what unit will be the result if you add kilometers to miles for example (probably the same unit as the left operand, but it adds cognitive overhead)

So decide on your use case. Whether you have

```
function myFunctionThatDoesSomethingUsefulWithDistanceInMeters(Meters $distance) {}
```

or

```
function myFunctionThatDoesSomethingUsefulWithDistanceAndItChosesUnitBySomeInternalLogic(DistanceInterface $distance) {}
```

or

```
function myFunctionThatDoesSomethingUsefulWithDistanceInUnitChosenByConsumerOfThisFunction(Distance $distance) {}
```

Also for the multiplication, that probably does not belong to distance unless you mean multiplication by constant. Multiplyiing two distances is not a distance anymore. You would need a system of units that can deal with combinations of any SI units and probably too complex for what you'Re trying to achieve here...

Comment: thansk for you feedback, I will have a read thru and digest. We do intend to add additonal units in the future, this is just a starting point. I do like the removal of unit validation, it didn't feel right the way it was.

Comment: I like the idea that there could be more than two units. Using an internal distance in meters makes perfect sense as soon as there are more than two units.